# How to read my end yaml config file in vue pages?

Tags: vue.js, yaml, config, nuxt.js

I am using nuxt and `config.yml` with `.config.yml` extended file. And I want to read finally generated config in any page I want. How to do that?

If I add `const config = require('config-yml');` in .vue file or in any plugin .js I had a lot of errors compilations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found.

```
env: {
   config: config
}
```

in nuxt.config.js

But not found how to get from .config.yml